# Как напечатать файл excel из командной строки?

Tags: excel, windows-7

Здравствуйте! подскажите пожалуйста как можно напечатать файл excel используя командную строку windows при этом не отображать excel файл, а сразу отправлять на печать? или может есть какой то аргумент командной строки для печати excel файла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аргумента для печати в excel раньше не было. Может что-то изменилось с тех пор? Не знаю.

Можно составить скрипт для Windows Script Host на VBScript или JScript, который запускаются в командной строке с помощью cscript.exe. Готовые скрипты легко находятся в интернете. Надо только в гугле написать ключевые слова: excel print command line.
Так же можно применить powershell.
Вообще можете использовать любой скриптовый язык, каким владеете, лишь бы он умел "автоматить" OLE Automation.
В скрипте создаётся объект excel и на этом объекте вызываются нужные методы для открытия файла, для его печати, в общем всё что хотите. При этом сам excel можно показать, а можно и спрятать. (В своё время на Perl таким образом составлял отчёты в excel)

Поправленный скрипт печати xls. Оригинальный на  http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/513760-what-is-the-command-line-print-switch-in-excel.html

```
Const xlDoNotSaveChanges = 2

Dim fso, oXL, oWkbk

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

oXL.Visible = False

If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Quit
Else
    For A = 0 To (WScript.Arguments.Count - 1)
        If (Right(WScript.Arguments.Item(A), 3) = "xls") AND fso.FileExists(WScript.Arguments.Item(A)) Then
            Set oWkbk = oXL.Workbooks.Open(WScript.Arguments.Item(A))
            oWkbk.PrintOut
            oWkbk.Close xlDoNotSaveChanges
        End If
    Next
End If

oXL.Quit
Set fso = Nothing
Set oXL = Nothing
```

Comment: `cscript.exe C:\Test\PrintWkbk.vbs "C:\xlFiles\Text.xls"` cscript.exe - для запуска скриптов в консольном режиме. Как раз то, что нужно для командной строки. Есть ещё wscript.exe - для запуска в оконном режиме.

Comment: запустил данный скрипт [ссылка](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/513760-what-is-the-command-line-print-switch-in-excel.html) получаю ошибку: Предполагается наличие окончания инструкции

Comment: @Vlad Хотя в VBScript не силён, но думаю ошибка в длинном IF. Там за каким-то ... затесалось подчёркивание. В ответ вставил исправленный скрипт.

Comment: ошибки нет, но на печать что то ничего не отправляется )

Comment: @Vlad В системе принтер по умолчанию назначен? Ещё попробуйте oXL.Visible = True, чтобы посмотреть открывается ли Ваш файл? Может что-то не так с аргументами в командной строке? Файл xls или xlsx (или какое сейчас модное расширение)?

Comment: да, принтер назначен, расширение файлов xlsx, в скрипте тоже подправил на xlsx, visible true тоже не помогает, видимо он вообще файл не открывает почему то.

Comment: Так `Right(WScript.Arguments.Item(A), 4) = "xlsx"`? 3 на 4 заменили при замене xls на xslx? (Вообще этот if можно убрать полностью)

Comment: Заработал скрипт! только печатает все листы, надо разобраться как печатать определённый лист, если не сложно можно строчку, просто сам на VB ни когда не писал. или хотя бы ссылку как это сделать. Вообще необходимость возникла в связи с тем что на С# для работы с Excel есть Interop который не очень хорошо работает, исключения появляются.

Comment: Надо получить объект worksheet. У него тоже есть printOut. Предлагаю порыться в MSDN или в помощи Excel. API excel (и прочего офиса) что в c#, что в vb - одинаковый. Может отсюда получится начать. https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194464.aspx Искать что-то лучше нету времени.

Comment: Честно говоря хотел как то обойти эту технику COM через класс процесс. т.е. запуск файла Excel на печать с указание Argument (аргумент командной строки т.е. указать какой лист конкретно печатать и указать чтобы Excel не открывался, а сразу уходил на печать)

Comment: Тогда лучше в c# это делать. Раз уж микрософт для автоматизации предлагает только COM.